# Limit Struts2 file upload max size without uploading the whole file

Tags: java, upload, struts2, max

I am trying to implement a file upload in JSP/Struts2, and I noted a strange behaviour.
I declared my action that way in struts.xml to limit file size to 1MB

```
<action name="massInsert" class="massInsertAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">
             image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg
        </param>
        <param name="maximumSize">1000000</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>

    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/massInsert/massInsert.jsp</result>
    <result name="validationError">/WEB-INF/jsp/massInsert/massInsert.jsp</result>
</action>
```

it works pretty well, non image files and images over 1MB throw an error.
The only issue is that the file that was too big got fully uploaded on the server temp folder anyway before being deleted.

Is there a way to stop the uploading as soon as the limit is hit ?

**Edit:**
Quaternion's solution works, when the request goes over the maximum set with the following line an error is thrown and everything stops. No file is written to disk

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two file size parameters one has to do with individual files sizes the other with the the maximum multi part file size. This is in place because you can receive an array of files if you wish (just change the setters type from File to File[], so easy), say **struts.multipart.maxSize** is set to 10MB and file size (**maximumSize**) is set to 1 MB you should be able to receive 10 1MB files. So the buffer should be allowed to grow to 10 MB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" 
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />

    <action name="doUpload" class="com.example.UploadAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">500000</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <interceptor-ref name="validation"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>

    <result name="success">good_result.jsp</result>
    </action>
</struts>
```

Source: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/File+Upload#FileUpload-FileSizeLimits