# Struts2 - Upload photo from Android to Server via Restful

Tags: android, web-services, web, struts2

I would like to upload photo from Android client to Web Server via Restful like this:

- URL:

> http://domain.com/users/{user_id}/list

- Method: POST
- Content-type Image/JPEG
- Server receive photo. But I don't know how to receive and save to folder.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: I tried to post an image from Android client. So I don't know how to receive image by struts2. Example: Android upload file -> struts2: PhotosController handle photo -> Save to folder of server

Comment: The second link provides file upload code for struts2, I'll leave a full solution to someone else although between these links there shouldn't be much left http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821334/limit-struts2-file-upload-max-size-without-uploading-the-whole-file

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330503/how-to-display-imagebolb-type-in-jsp-page-from-mysql-db-in-struts-2-using-hibe